# Writing data to Excel in an Asp.net application via OleDb

Tags: excel, oledb, export-to-excel

So I have no problem inserting rows into a named range in an excel sheet using an OleDbConnection like this:

```
string con_string = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;\";", tempfilename)
```

And then I insert rows into the named range so that users of the application can download the resulting excel workbook, enter some changes to the data into it, then upload those changes later and have them read by the application into the database.

It all works great when I run the application on my workstation.  But when I run it on our test server, the sheet that gets built doesn't have any named ranges in it, which is crazy, because it just built all the data by inserting into this named range, but it doesn't, so that when the user attempts to upload that workbook with changes, they get an error due to the OleDb driver not finding that named range.

Any clues as to why this works on the workstation, but not on the server?

Comment: Do you still need a help on this? How big is your data?

Comment: I had to abandon the idea of reading from a named range , it was a bummer.